# Installing TensorFlow on M1 Chip - Issues. - PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

Tags: python, tensorflow, apple-m1

I have an M1 chip but am having issues installing Tensorflow. I've tried a number of different methods but I feel im completely stuck.

I was following this particular tutorial - https://betterdatascience.com/install-tensorflow-2-7-on-macbook-pro-m1-pro/ -

but came unstuck when installing.

This is the error:

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- tensorflow-deps

Current channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/apple/osx-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/apple/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

Note I have anaconda already installed so is it a case of uninstalling it? I'm really stuck.

Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/697846

Comment: I tried this method - nothing helped. I also tried running miniforge3 with the dependencies in a new environment. Still didnt work

Comment: try changing the CONDA_SUBDIR by executing 'conda env config vars set CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-arm64' in the environment.

Comment: I came through with the same error, did you manage to solve this? @Dove

Comment: Hi @OceanSky_U - Watch this vid. It solved it for me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nY5lDBXdOg

Answer (score 2):

I could able to install Tensorflow on Mac Os without any issue with these following steps

```
python3 -m venv ~/tensorflow-metal
source ~/tensorflow-metal/bin/activate
python -m pip install -U pip
python -m pip install tensorflow-macos
python -m pip install tensorflow-metal
```

Comment: Getting this error : ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-macos (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-macos

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/697846

adding `subdir: osx-arm64` to `~\.condarc` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/697846?answerId=748166022#748166022

You probably installed the x86_64 version of Anaconda. You need to install the arm64 version of Anaconda for it to find the package.